# Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, enums, avro

Our Kafka producer provides an Avro schema that contains several enums, where each enum is encapsulated in a map with same name.

**Avro schema**

```
{
  "name": "myType",
  "type": {
    "name": "myType",
    "type": "map",
    "values": {
      "name": "myType",
      "type": "enum",
      "symbols": ["MY_ONE", "MY_TWO","MY_THREE"]
    },
    "default": "MY_ONE"
  }
},
```

**Example content**

```
"myType":{
   "myTypw":"MY_TWO"
},
```

When trying to consume data an exception in thrown...

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 1148
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.read(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:409) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:113) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1420) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting com.myType
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:308) ~[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:86) ~[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readEnum(ResolvingDecoder.java:259) ~[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
```

Assumption is that error is caused by using same name for map and enum. But is this really an issue?
Does it mean that the source schema is invalid? Or is it an issue on the Acro deserializer?

Comment: I think you need to give the FQDN for the enum, otherwise, it assumes it's just a regular string, but yeah, the duplicate names don't help. Can you share your producer code?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks for your feedback - unluckily I'm only on the consumer side and have no access to producer code. Just can share schema and content as shown above.